# Can I reduce my browser to 'bare bones' network activitiy?

Tags: bandwidth

I quite often tether my mac though my phone and obviously this results in less bandwidth being available.  Is it possible to have a browser set up to use the smallest possible amount of bandwidth? What are the major things to turn off(on) to reduce the amount of data I'm piping though the machine.

Note: I'm actually NOT concerned about cost - I'm completely concerned with speed and responsiveness...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit broad and difficult to answer, particularly as you haven't mentioned what browser you are using. However, here are some ideas:

- Install [AdblockPlus](https://adblockplus.org) if you have Firefox or Chrome, as adverts can really slow things down
- Consider disabling Flash off completely as it is rarely used for anything useful these days.
- You could try changing your user agent-string (with a plugin like [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)) to that of a mobile browser to trick websites into giving you their mobile version which will normally use less bandwidth and load quicker. Of course on some sites you may have a lot of wasted space if you have a high resolution screen.
- There are "accelerator" services available that compress the data you send/receive to speed up loading times. One of the easiest ways to start using one is to switch to [Opera](http://www.opera.com/computer/mac) then enable the **Opera Turbo** service in the settings;
- If you are relying on your tethered connection a lot then you might want to think about buying a mobile broadband dongle/router instead as these devices can sometimes get a better signal and perform faster.