# Reduce bandwidth usage when web browsing?

Tags: linux, compression, bandwidth, tethering

If I have a 1GB tethering allowance per month.  Is it possible to somehow compress the websites I visit so they use less bandwidth to reach my screen?

Comment: This would be impossible because the webserver you have requested would have to perform the compression which would use additional memory and processor overhead... and then there is the browser you are using, it wouldn't understand the compression used so it wouldn't know how to render a page...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I reduce my browser to 'bare bones' network activitiy?](http://superuser.com/questions/771695/can-i-reduce-my-browser-to-bare-bones-network-activitiy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many/most web servers already compress things as much as possible where they can, to save on their own bandwidth usage.

If you REALLY need to reduce bandwidth while browsing, perhaps use a text-based browser like [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)), and/or a 'web-to-text' service like [www.textise.net](http://textise.wordpress.com/about-textise/).

> Textise is a new way of looking at the Web. It’s an Internet tool that removes everything from a web page except for its text...
>   What’s really cool, though, is that links are retained, although these are no ordinary links: click one and you’re transported to another text-only page, and that page leads to another, and another, and another… You stay in Textise World until you click the Back To Reality link.

Comment: This seems to work, microsoft.com's homepage is about 870kb, with textise, it's about 70kb.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to request the mobile version of the website instead of the full page - http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/31947-42-view-websites-mobile-device

Answer (score 0):

I use the chrome plugin, *[Text Only Mode](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-only-mode/nelklgbagpchkmoipfpcbbjjbdbjhgid?hl=en)*.  By default, all pages will be delivered in text, with no pictures or videos (kinda like a more user-friendly version of Lynx).  When you want to see something in its full glory, just toggle the plugin off.

I live out in the middle of nowhere, and my tether is my only lifeline to the Internet when I'm not at work.  This helps keep my bandwidth under control.

Comment: Just tired this and it doesn't seem to make much difference.  Went to Microsoft.com with this disabled which used about 870kb bandwidth.  I then enabled this plugin, went to microsoft.com and it used about 860kb bandwidth.